# Is the front closet wall load bearing?

Tags: framing, structural, load-bearing

Closet in question we are trying to remove for a custom closet. Not sure if this wall is load bearing. House is a town house and the back wall of the closet is a shared wall. Wall to the right is an exterior wall and the left side is internal.

Top plate is wrapped in plastic. Attic/crawl space is above this.

In the custom closet we have space for vertical 2x4s to reconnect to the top plates. But only a total of 3-5 columns spread across the entire top plate length. Not 4 centered in the middle.

[image: Black top plate & open header.]

[image: outside of closet]

Comment: If the framing over the top of the doors is one or two 2x4 with their faces pointed downward, then that's typically non-bearing. The black piece is interesting, though. Is it made out of steel, is it painted wood, or is it something else?

Comment: Do you mean the header's orientation? The top plate is wrapped in plastic, I am thinking for the attic.

Comment: [Many other similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+closet+wall+load+bearing)

Comment: Thank you for the links